# Where does Groovy Grape get the dependencies from?

Tags: maven, groovy, dependency-management

Geb installation instructions (http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#installation__usage) say to use the following `Grapes` annotation to get Geb dependencies.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:0.9.3"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.41.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.41.0")
])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.1!httpclient.jar, download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3!httpcore.jar, download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.8!commons-codec.jar]
```

From what I can tell, the dependency is available here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpclient%7C4.3.1%7Cjar

Does `Grape` not use Maven Central? How do I get it to resolve the dependecy?

Comment: the problem is more likely on your end, as above code worked for me (all files downloaded)

Comment: strange... i have tried it from 2 different machines with 2 different connections over 2 days... the problem persists. is it possible that you downloaded the file in question as part of some other project and it is now cached in your local maven repo?

Comment: i have removed my ~/.groovy/grapes/ dir and ran `grape resolve org.seleniumhq.selenium selenium-firefox-driver 2.41.0` which then transitivly loaded the file mentioned in your post

Comment: i just tried the same thing and got this: `Error in resolve:
        Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.3.1!httpclient.jar, download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.3!httpcore.jar, download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3!commons-logging.jar, download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.8!commons-codec.jar]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `.groovy/grapes` fixed all my dependency resolution problems.

Answer (score 2):

according to the docs at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape the default is maven central.  you can add your own repos using `@GrabResolver(name='restlet', root='http://maven.restlet.org/')` (see link).  also you can use the command line tool `grape` to further investigate into the error like e.g. `grape -V install org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient 4.3.1`.